# Java - IntelliJ generated executable jar not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I have generated an executable jar in IntelliJ IDE. But when I try executing the jar file from windows folder it does not work. When I try running the .jar file from within the IDE in debug mode it gives the below error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in D:\... the file path
```

To generate the executable jar I referred to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)

I referred to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982327/no-main-manifest-attribute-intellij) for the no main manifest attribute issue but dint help as in my case its a Gradle build

(Note: If I execute the program(.java file) from within the IDE it works fine, so I believe the issue is not with the program)

Hope the issue I face is clear, await guidance

Comment: You will find this question answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952713/wrong-manifest-mf-in-intellij-idea-created-jar

Comment: @MeganD that link I had checked earlier, but it doesn't help. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adopted Gradle build tool to generate Jar.